# How to upgrade project targetSdk from 19 to 23

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

Currently I am using target 19 (Android 4.4) and i have attached support library v4 in jar. I want to upgrade targetSdk to  API 23 to handle Runtime Permissions, hovewer there is no clear explonation in web how to do it, and changing targetSdk in Manifest and gradle isn't enough because classes responsible for runtime permission from API 23 are not found.. could you tell me step by step what should i do ?

And second one : should i use android-support v4 or v7 or other version ? what you would advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> support library v4 in jar

Why jar and not `compile ...` in build.gradle?

> hovewer there is no clear explonation in web how to do it

There tons of posts and plenty of libs that can help. Just google for it.

> changing targetSdk in Manifest and gradle isn't enough because classes responsible for runtime permission from API 23 are not found

You need to change build SDK to API 23 to compile that code.

> should i use android-support v4 or v7 or other version

Runtime Permissions are not related to support library. Leave it as is.

Comment: It is in jar, because this lib is delivered to many clients, and they don't have to bother if they have specific support-library installed in sdk, or not.